# Converting exchange email to smtp email

Tags: vba, outlook-2003

Is it possible to convert the exchange email to smtp email.  I could find some help while googling, but the solutions are not feasible as I'm using the older version (outlook 2003).

When I check MailItem.SenderEmailAddress property the values in the property looks like this format

```
/O=MYCOMPANY/OU=COUNTRY/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=joseph
```

I want to convert this to smtp email which should be

```
joseph@mail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this way for my .Net:

```
service.ResolveName(emailAddress.Address).First().Mailbox.Address
// emailAddress.Address = "/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange(abc)/cn=Recipients/cn=xyz"
// => abc@xyz.com
```

ResolveName method reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635548(v=exchg.80).aspx

I am using .Net instead of VBA. However hope will inspire your VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

```
MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

I know this works for Outlook 2010, but your mileage may vary with 2003.

Comment: `GetExchangeUser` needs a `UserId` class, currently, I get `EmailAddress` class. This will not work.