# Identify the email address in Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook

I m using this code

```
        Public Sub ProcessarAnexo(Email As MailItem)

        Dim DiretorioAnexos As String
        Dim MailID As String
        Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim objOLmail As Object
```

This is the folder where i need to save the attachments

```
        DiretorioAnexos = "C:\Separados\AlamoLogistica\"
        MailID = Email.EntryID
        Set Mail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(MailID)
```

In this part the code separes the attachment from the mail

```
        For Each anexo In Mail.Attachments
             If Right(anexo.FileName, 3) = "xml" Then
                 anexo.SaveAsFile DiretorioAnexos & anexo.FileName
             End If

             If Right(anexo.FileName, 3) = "zip" Then
                anexo.SaveAsFile DiretorioAnexos & anexo.FileName
             End If
        Next
        Set Mail = Nothing
```

This code works, perhaps i need to separe the attachments by the email  adreess

i have write this :

```
          Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
          Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
          Dim appOl As New Outlook.Application

          Dim DiretorioAnexos As String
          Dim MailID As String
          Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
          Dim objOLmail As Object
```

Here  the code must assign "Caixa de Entrada" or "Inbox" to the Mapifolder Inbox

```
     Set ns = appOl.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

     For Each objOLmail In Inbox.Items
```

Here if  the mail from longfe@ifdcontroladoria.com.br must go to the folder ""C:\Separados\AlamoLogistica\""

```
    If InStr(objOLmail.SenderEmailAddress, "longfe@ifdcontroladoria.com.br") >= 0 Then
       DiretorioAnexos = "C:\Separados\AlamoLogistica\"
        MailID = Email.EntryID
        Set Mail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(MailID)

        For Each anexo In Mail.Attachments
             If Right(anexo.FileName, 3) = "xml" Then
                 anexo.SaveAsFile DiretorioAnexos & anexo.FileName
             End If

             If Right(anexo.FileName, 3) = "zip" Then
                anexo.SaveAsFile DiretorioAnexos & anexo.FileName
             End If
        Next
    End If

 Next
     Set Mail = Nothing
```

but the code dont work what i m doing wrong????

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the `SenderEmailAddress` field is producing something similar to the output in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13516624/493055).

Try replacing `objOLmail.SenderEmailAddress` in your If statement with `objOLmail.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`