# How do I include reply's when reading outlook email with VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm reading Outlook Inbox and Sent folder emails for a given address and populating an Access table.  My routine isn't picking up the "Reply" emails.  I assumed they would be in the sent folder.  I don't have any subfolders at this time.  Any thoughts on what I'm missing or don't understand?  This is my first venture into reading Outlook data.

```
Sub GetFromInbox(strInboxSent As String, strForAddress As String)
    Dim olFolderInboxSent As Integer

    Select Case strInboxSent
        Case "InBox"
            olFolderInboxSent = 6   '6 = InBox, Sent = 5
        Case "Sent"
            olFolderInboxSent = 5   
    End Select

    Dim olApp As Object, olNs As Object
    Dim oRootFldr As Object ' Root folder to start
    Dim lCalcMode As Long

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oRootFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInboxSent) 

    GetFromFolder oRootFldr, strForAddress, olFolderInboxSent
    Set oRootFldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub GetFromFolder(oFldr As Object, strForAddress As String, intInboxSent As Integer)

    'Load Worktable with sent emails
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * From wtblEmails"
    rst.Open cmd

    Dim oItem As Object, oSubFldr As Object

    ' Process all mail items in this folder
    For Each oItem In oFldr.Items
    Debug.Print TypeName(oItem)
        If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then
            With oItem
                Select Case intInboxSent
                    Case 6
                        If .SenderEmailAddress = strForAddress Then
                            'Debug.Print .Subject, .SenderName, .SenderEmailAddress, .EntryID
                            rst.AddNew
                            rst!weDate = .CreationTime
                            rst!weRcvdSent = "R"
                            rst!weWith = .SenderEmailAddress
                            rst!weSubject = .Subject
                            rst!weBody = .Body
                            rst!weid = .EntryID
                            rst.Update
                        End If
                    Case 5
                        If .To = strForAddress Then
                            'Debug.Print .Subject, .SenderName, .SenderEmailAddress, .EntryID
                            rst.AddNew
                            rst!weDate = .CreationTime
                            rst!weRcvdSent = "S"
                            rst!weWith = .To
                            rst!weSubject = .Subject
                            rst!weBody = .Body
                            rst!weid = .EntryID
                            rst.Update
                        End If
                    End Select
            End With
        End If
    Next

    ' Recurse all Subfolders
    For Each oSubFldr In oFldr.Folders
        GetFromFolder oSubFldr, strForAddress, intInboxSent
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the emails in question actually in the "sent" folder?

Comment: This could be a case of exchange address versus SMTP address. Do a debug.print on the address of reply mail in the Sent folder.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516624/converting-exchange-email-to-smtp-email

Comment: The debug explains why, but I'm not seeing a property that may be the solution.  In the initial sent mail item, the ".TO" is the email address for the recipient. But in the replies I send related to that email, the ".TO" is the recipients name, not the address.  When I look through the properties, I'm not seeing one that may be the recipients email address in the reply entry.  Thanks for getting me this far.  Any thoughts on how to read emails and replies sent to a given address?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found that works.  The list of recipient address for a sent email are found here.  For each email item, I call this function to see if the address I'm looking for was in the list of recipients.

```
Public Function fncWasMailSentTo(mail As Outlook.MailItem, strAddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
    Set recips = mail.Recipients

    fncWasMailSentTo = False

    For Each recip In recips
        Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
        'Debug.Print recip.Name & " SMTP=" & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
        If pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) = strAddress Then
            fncWasMailSentTo = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```